# Como verificar intervalo de dados?

Tags: mysql, sql

Ao solicitar uma reserva de veículo, o sistema insere o código de hora de saída e de retorno previsto (preferimos trabalhar com códigos fixos ao invés dos horários a fim de facilitar a programação). O que acontece é que quando a reserva é feita em horários à frente (por exemplo, estou reservando de manhã um horário a tarde) o sistema permite outra reserva que passe "por cima" da reserva anterior.

Por exemplo, se eu reservar das 9:00 as 10:00, o meu `select` não exibe esse intervalo depois da confirmação, mas se alguém reservar das 8:00 às 11:00 no mesmo dia ele vai deixar gravar. Com o `select` abaixo eu não exibo os horários reservados, alguma ideia de como fazer a validação?

```
SELECT H.* FROM HORARIOS H
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM RESERVAS R
    WHERE H.COD BETWEEN R.COD_HORA_SAIDA AND
          R.COD_HORA_PREVISTA-1 AND
          R.COD_VEICULO = :codveiculo AND
          DATE_FORMAT(DATA_SAIDA, \'%d-%m-%Y\') = :codcalendario AND
          r.ativa = 1)
ORDER BY H.COD
```

Abaixo tem um exemplo da situação que ocorre:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Não consegui entender qual é o seu problema. Pode explicar melhor por favor?

Comment: Por exemplo, insiro na tabela "reservas" a minha reserva, por exemplo, das 14:00 às 16:00. O sistema bloqueia a exibição desse intervalo, então ninguém poderá reservar esse mesmo horário. Mas se alguém quiser reservar das 13:00 (horário que está livre) até as 17:00 (horário também livre) vai conseguir, passando por cima da reserva anterior.

Comment: Então se alguém quiser reservar das 13:00 até às 17:00 não deveria conseguir reservar também, certo?

Comment: Como vc salva esse código da hora no banco, @Diego? Eu pergunto por que, talvez, se fosse criado uma segunda tabela, que funcionasse como lista, e fosse armazenado as horas que o carro permaneceria, algo como (seguindo o seu exemplo) `[14 15 16]`, poderia ser facil mensurar, e o seu `CONTAINS` funcionaria, verificando do registro salvo para o registro a ser salvo.

Comment: Outra pergunta, se fosse selecionado das 13h as 15h, e se já existisse um registro das 14h as 16h, não deveria ser permitido?

Comment: @Jorge B. exatamente, se ele quisesse das 13:00 às 14:00 poderia, mas das 13:00 às 17:00 deveria ser bloqueado.

Comment: @GustavoCinque eu tenho uma tabela de horarios, de meia em meia hora. Em todo sistema eu trato as horas com o código. Vc diz ao invés de gravar um intervalo, gravar todo tempo que ele fica "fora"? Tipo, reserva da hora codigo 1 ao 5 gravar todo intervalo (1,2,3,4,5) no banco?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo. Assim vc poderia comparar as duas listas, se elas contem os mesmos elementos. Mas vc ainda gravaria as colunas de entrada e saida, essa segunda tabela seria para a validação dessa parte do sistema.

Comment: Essa seria uma solução de banco, vc poderia implementar a mesma ideia programaticamente.

Comment: @GustavoCinque estou tentando montar algo com o PHP, mas realmente isto está complicado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT count(*) as flag FROM HORARIOS H
                     WHERE EXISTS (
                           SELECT * FROM RESERVAS R
                                WHERE H.COD BETWEEN R.COD_HORA_SAIDA AND
                                      R.COD_HORA_PREVISTA-1 AND
                                      R.COD_VEICULO = 2 AND
                                      DATE_FORMAT(DATA_SAIDA, '%d-%m-%Y') = :data_saida and
                                      (h.cod between :codsaida and :codretorno) and
                                      r.ativa = 1)
                                ORDER BY H.COD;
```

Dessa forma, fiz um if, se o resultado for mais que 1 tem algo no intervalo e dá erro. 
Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos lá.
Tentarei utilizar um pseudo código, pois não tenho nenhum fundamento em php.

Dadas as váriaveis:

```
horaEntradaBanco = registroBanco.horaEntrada;
horaSaidaBanco = registroBanco.horaSaida;
horaEntradaMarkup = $('#campoHorarioEntrada').getValue();
horaSaidaMarkup = $('#campoHorarioSaida').getValue();
```

Você conseguiria fazer as validações a seguir:

```
if(horaEntradaMarkup<=horaEntradaBanco && horaSaidaMarkup>=horaSaidaBanco){
    //bloquear utilização de horário
    //exemplo de entrada no if: Horas banco: 14h~15h
                                Horas Markup: 13h~17h
} else if(horaEntradaMarkup<=horaEntradaBanco && horaSaidaMarkup<=horaSaidaBanco) {
    //bloquear utilização de horário
    //exemplo de entrada no if: Horas banco: 14h~16h
                                Horas Markup: 13h~15h

    //Aqui eu não sei se já está sendo validado ou não, já que vc só falou do exemplo acima.
}
```

Ve se dá certo.

Comment: A sua lógica está correta, mas vou ter que adaptar ela, pois posso ter várias entradas no mesmo dia e de alguma forma preciso passar por todas.